# Production-ready alternative to Archlinux

Tags: web-server, linux-distribution

I'm currently looking for an Archlinux alternative suitable for production servers, which means less "bleeding-edge" software but otherwise it should be really as close to Arch as possible, here are the main requirements.

- Systemd-based
- the package manager shouldn't touch config files; I don't want any of this "setup wizard" black magic commonly found on Debian and Ubuntu server; it may be good for beginners but will do more harm than good in my case
- [Arch-style manual installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide), with a base system as minimal as possible, no extra services (imagine my sadness when I found out that CentOS installed about 10 services that weren't even applicable to my case as I wasn't running it in a VM nor using the specific RAID cards these services were designed to monitor)
- no NetworkManager nor Firewalld heresy. Seriously, this is a server, not a desktop machine and the default `iptables-save` is more than enough. Again, looking at you CentOS and RHEL.
- ready-to-use support for Docker or plain LXC; if possible via a package to install without compiling everything from source.
- no bug reporting (like ABRT) or telemetry/stats of any kind. I don't even want to have such tools installed on the computer. The machines should keep a low profile and pinging an external web service for whatever reason is not acceptable, no matter what kind of privacy policy nonsense they put up.
- common servers and languages (OpenSMTPd, Postfix, Dovecot, Nginx, PHP-FPM, MySQL/MariaDB, Node.js, Ruby, Python) should be available as packages
- SELinux or equivalent RBAC support

Comment: Obviously, you discounted https://www.gentoo.org/ ?

Comment: @Mawg I just haven't tried it (and I'm asking the question because I'm looking for someone having enough experience to tell me which one is best, otherwise I would just try all of them myself), but it looks just as bleeding-edge as Arch..

Comment: Not an answer. But even though everywhere on the internet, all users of Archlinux recommend against using it in production, there is a little paragraph at the end of [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance) that describes a `linux-lts` package. I find it well worth more digging, as I am looking for the same thing as you are. Edit: Addition: [Awesome Wiki entry for you.](https://m.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1p1zv2/archlinux_stable_server/)